# Will different java versions create different serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization, version

I have updated my java version from 1.6 to 1.8. When I try to deploy my project in weblogic (12c),  I am getting below error.

> java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5171479712008793097, local class serialVersionUID = 736080306599024264

Do I need to re generate serialVersionUID , which created using java version 1.6 ?

Please help

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the compiler version matters. The [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) Javadoc says (in part)

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification. However, it is *strongly recommended* that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during deserialization.

Comment: However in practice if this ever happened it would break the world. I've never seen it in 22 years.

Comment: And in any case the dependency is on the compiler, so all installations of the same compiled .class file can be expected to yield the same `serialVersionUID` regardless of user JVM version.